# terraform aws_s3_bucket region that is different to the aws provider region gets created in the same provider region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to manage AWS S3 buckets with terraform and noticed that there's a `region` parameter for the resource.

I have an AWS provider that is configured for 1 region, and would like to use that provider to create S3 buckets in multiple regions if possible. My S3 buckets have a lot of common configuration that I don't want to repeat, so i have a local module to do all the repetitive stuff....

In `mod-s3-bucket/main.tf`, I have something like:

```
variable bucket_region {}
variable bucket_name {}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
   region = var.bucket_region
   bucket = var.bucket_name
}
```

And then in `main.tf` in the parent directory (tf root):

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

module "somebucket" {
  source = "mod-s3-bucket"
  bucket_region = "us-east-1"
  bucket_name = "useast1-bucket"
}

module "anotherbucket" {
  source = "mod-s3-bucket"
  bucket_region = "us-east-2"
  bucket_name = "useast2-bucket"
}
```

When I run a `terraform apply` with that, both buckets get created in us-east-1 - is this expected behaviour? My understanding is that region should make the buckets get created in different regions.

Further to that, if I run a terraform plan after bucket creation, I see the following:

```
       ~ region                      = "us-east-1" -> "us-east-2"
```

on the 1 bucket, but after an apply, the region has not changed.

I know I can easily solve this by using a 2nd, aliased AWS provider, but am asking specifically about how the `region` parameter is meant to work for an `aws_s3_bucket` resource (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html#region)

- terraform v0.12.24
- aws v2.64.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region attribute in s3 bucket resource isn't parsed as expected, there is a bug for this:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/592

The multiple provider approach is needed.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll need to do something like the docs show in this example for `Replication Configuration`: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html#using-replication-configuration

```
# /root/main.tf

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-east-2"
  region = "us-east-2"
}

module "somebucket" {
  source = "mod-s3-bucket"
  bucket_region = "us-east-1"
  bucket_name = "useast1-bucket"
}

module "anotherbucket" {
  source = "mod-s3-bucket"
  provider = "aws.us-east-2"
  bucket_region = "us-east-2"
  bucket_name = "useast2-bucket"
}
```

```
# /mod-s3-bucket/main.tf

variable provider {
   type = string
   default = "aws"
}
variable bucket_region {}
variable bucket_name {}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
   provider = var.provider
   region = var.bucket_region
   bucket = var.bucket_name
}
```

I've never explicitly set the provider like that though in a resource but based on the docs it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @theonlyrao - as per my original question - "I know I can easily solve this by using a 2nd, aliased AWS provider, but am asking specifically about how the region parameter is meant to work for an aws_s3_bucket resource"

Answer (score 1):

Terraform informs you if you try to set the region directly in the resource:

```
╷
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket,
│   on s3.tf line 10, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket":
│   28:   region                      = "us-east-1"
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "region": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.
```

Terraform uses the configuration of the `provider`, where the region is set, for managing resources. Alternatively, as already mentioned, you can use multiple configurations for the same provider by making use of the `alias` meta-argument.

> You can optionally define multiple configurations for the same
> provider, and select which one to use on a per-resource or per-module
> basis. The primary reason for this is to support multiple regions for
> a cloud platform; other examples include targeting multiple Docker
> hosts, multiple Consul hosts, etc.
>
> ...
>
> A provider block without an alias argument is the default
> configuration for that provider. Resources that don't set the provider
> meta-argument will use the default provider configuration that matches
> the first word of the resource type name. [link](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration)